# OpenCV image conversion from mat to BufferedImage

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I get error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Image is loaded in mat type then is converted to BufferedImage for displaying.
in between some OpenCV function will be used. Converter in main can't be run due to error mag. What is the error?

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import  java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.lang.Math;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class Tutorial1 {



     public static void main(String[] args){

         converter();
     }

     public void converter(){

         Mat matImage= Highgui.imread(getClass().getResource("/lena.png").getPath());
         BufferedImage bufImage =  Mat2BufferedImage(matImage);
         displayImage(bufImage);
     }

    public BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m){
    //source: http://answers.opencv.org/question/10344/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui/
    //Fastest code
    //The output can be assigned either to a BufferedImage or to an Image

     int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
     if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
         type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
     }
     int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
     byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
     m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
     BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
     final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
     System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
     return image;
    }

    public void displayImage(Image img2)
    {   
    //BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("/HelloOpenCV/lena.png"));
    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());        
    frame.setSize(img2.getWidth(null)+50, img2.getHeight(null)+50);     
    JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
    lbl.setIcon(icon);
    frame.add(lbl);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that you are making a static reference to a method that is not declared as static. So for example consider this code:

```
class Example{
    public void doSomething(){
         ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Here you see that a static reference is made from inside the main method to the non-static method `doSomething()` this will yield the same error that you are getting now.

So now for the solution:
To solve this issue you can either add the static keyword to the method in question. So for my example that would mean that I would change my method from:

```
public void doSomething(){

}
```

To:

```
public static void doSomething(){

}
```

An other option is to create a new instance of the class with the method and then call it. This would be done like this (using my example).

```
class Example{
    public void doSomething(){
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example example = new Example();
        example.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Both of these solution will solve the problem but it's up to the programmer to determine wich way is better suited for the situation.

So the solution to your problem, your JDK should tell you what method you are trying the use in the wrong way by underlineing it in red. And then you only have to apply one of the two solutions.

I hope this helps :)

Edit #1:

In your case you are calling converter from you main method but converter is not static thus the error is thrown.

Edit #2:

So to solve it in your case you could change your main method to this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     new Tutorial1().converter();
 }
```

Comment: @Brunts No problem good luck with the rest of your project :)